# Everything looks fine in the Search Console, but Google is not really indexing my site

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, google-index

I hope this question is not too generic.

Some weeks ago, I set up a new Q&A site for my collaboration.

I have added it to my search console dash board and I have submitted the sitemap.

Google lists 106 submitted URLs, but only 21 have been indexed. I can not see any errors on the dashboard.

Is this a normal behavior for a very low ranked web page? Should I just be patient and wait for people to link it more? Or is there something wrong with my configuration - somehow?

Comment: Sorry but this type of question has been asked many times in various forms already on Pro Webmasters. To add, submitting a sitemap to Google does not prompt their bot to crawl your site. Google allocates 'TIME' spent on each site, more priorty sites such as popular sites, get allocated more time... because of this your site will take several days, to weeks to fully index, this can be improved over time and how important Google believes your content is. Other than that use the search your find plenty of other questions and answers that will help with indexing issues.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. I understand why this question was marked as duplicate.